# in Coldfusion how do I add a 'column' to the struct inside an array?

Tags: coldfusion

For example I have array ads and inside it has images

```
ads
   images
      url = someurl
      title = sometitle
      *here I want to add prop = someprop 
   images
      url = someurl
      title = sometitle
      *here I want to add prop = someprop
ads
   images
      url = someurl
      title = sometitle
      *here I want to add prop = someprop
```

Now I loop

```
<cfloop array="ads" index="i">
   <cfloop array="i.images" index="j">
      <cfif somecondition>
         <cfset prop = 'yes'>
      <cfelse>
         <cfset prop = 'no'>
      </cfif>
      <cfset ArrayAppend(i.images[j],prop)> ???
   </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

I tried several things with the ArrayAppend, tried a StructAppend, but apparently I am unable to understand how I would go about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You can simply set the `prop` on the item in the images loop. This is assuming that the items in the `i.images` array are structures.

```
<cfloop array="ads" index="i">
   <cfloop array="i.images" index="j">
      <cfif somecondition>
         <cfset j.prop = 'yes'>
      <cfelse>
         <cfset j.prop = 'no'>
      </cfif>
   </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Indeed it was that simple! I was thinking way to complicated

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of an array attribute for cfloop, but I think this is what you're after

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(ads)#" index="i" step="1">
     <cfset ads[i]["newprop"] = newpropvalue>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Well, I had a loop in a loop and was struggling with that, so I did not find my answer in your solution, because I was struggling with the double loop particularly. I tried changing my loop in a from to loop and use a solution similar like yours, but I did not succeed. Array attribute does exist, see Scott's answer below that did the trick.